# Get text of edit text android with java

Tags: android

I have problem with edittext.
I get text of Edit text and I want to say if text in edit text is equal to "a"
do something
but its not working

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String adadrandom=editText.getText().toString();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (adadrandom=="a"){
                System.out.println("yes");
            }else {
                System.out.println("no");
            }
        }
    });
```

also i use .equals()
but again i see the same answer

Comment: You need to move `String adadrandom =...` to **inside** your `onClick` method, not outside like it is now (and not use ==)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `getText` code inside the onClick method, and compare the values with `equals` method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 String adadrandom=editText.getText().toString();
        if (adadrandom.equals("a")){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE should be warning you not to used `==` but to use `.equals`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String adadrandom = editText.getText().toString();
        //Use equals and by doing it on the a string you get 
        // null protection.
        if ("a".equals(adadradom)){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did but its not working and again the run shows no instead yes

Answer (score 0):

Place your getting text code in onClick method and replace `==` with `.equals` for ignore warning from IDE.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String adadrandom = editText.getText().toString();
        if (adadradom.contentEquals("a")){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It should be like this but it’s not working and again i just see no instead yes in

Answer (score 0):

- `.equals()` method for content comparison
- `==` operators for reference comparison

  ```
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String adadrandom = editText.getText().toString();
          String displayData = adadrandom.equals("a") ? "Yes" : "No";
          System.out.println(displayData);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately i see the same answer again

Comment: @pdbqtashakori is it not working?